# integration test of FluentValidation and exception message

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, fluentvalidation

I am using fluentvalidation as follows:

```
public class ProjectValidator : AbstractValidator<Project>
{
    public ProjectValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(project => project.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Project name cannot be empty.");
    }
}
```

in some service:

```
IValidator<Project> _projectValidator;
_projectValidator.ValidateAndThrow(project);
```

part of the integration test:

```
var validationException = Assert.Throws<ValidationException>(() => projectRepository.SaveOrUpdate(project));
Assert.That(validationException.Message, Is.EqualTo("Project name cannot be empty."));
```

This obviously does not work as validationException potentially contains many errors. Even if it only contains one error the string looks like this:

> Validation failed: -- Project name cannot be empty.

How would you check that the validation resulted/contains the specified validation message?:

> Project name cannot be empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make assertion against validationException.Errors collection:

```
Assert.IsNotNull(validationException.Errors.SingleOrDefault(error => error.ErrorMessage.Equals("Project name cannot be empty.")));
```

Or, you can do the same using [FluentAssertions](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/):

```
validationException.Errors.Should().Contain(error => error.ErrorMessage.Equals("Project name cannot be empty."));
```

Comment: Thanks. I always meant to use fluentassertion - your fluent assertion method works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. I thought you may like it and use it in conjunction with FluentValidation :)

Answer (score 1):

FluentValidations also includes a clean way to do this using FluentActions.

```
FluentActions.Invoking(() => projectRepository.SaveOrUpdate(project))
.Should()
.Throw<ValidationException>()
.WithMessage("Project name cannot be empty.");
```

More examples here: https://fluentassertions.com/exceptions/